# Android - spinner text color change does not work

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, textcolor

I would like to change text color of my spinner (I want to have the chosen value to be white).

I have red about this topic on this forum, but it doesnt helped me. I have created the layout xml file for my spinner (spin.xml). Here is what I have:

spin.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Array adapter in my onCreate() :

```
 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shift);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.shiftarray, R.layout.spin);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){



        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {

            selected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            ((TextView) spinner.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(1);
            Log.e("SELECT", selected);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    });
```

What should I do, to make it work please?
Than you. :)

Comment: Are you aware of using selectors? Also, I would go making custom adapter and doing that in getView().

Answer (score 2):

Simple and effective...

```
 private OnItemSelectedListener OnCatSpinnerCL = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {

        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(5);



    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
```